# Accessing an array within an array (ng-repeat)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data structure like this:

```
[
   {firstName: "John",
    secondName: "Smith",
    children: ["Fred", "Hannah"]
   },
   {firstName: "Daniel",
    secondName: "Evans",
    children: ["Maggie", "Eddie", "Maria"]
   }
]
```

I want to use ng-repeat to return the CHILDREN of each person object, in a continuous list.

Like so:

```
<ul>    
    <li>Fred</li>
    <li>Hannah</li>
    <li>Maggie</li>
    <li>Eddie</li>
    <li>Maria</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: That is an array of objects, which has an array, try thinking of it like that and post some code on how you tried to access it.

Comment: Are you not outputting the parent? Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `reduce` your data structure before presenting it to the ng-repeat.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'my.controllers'
]);

var controllers = angular.module('my.controllers', []);

controllers.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  var people = [{
    firstName: "John",
    secondName: "Smith",
    children: ["Fred", "Hannah"]
  }, {
    firstName: "Daniel",
    secondName: "Evans",
    children: ["Maggie", "Eddie", "Maria"]
  }, {
   firstName:"Childless",
   secondName: "Parent"
  },
  { 
   firstName:"Jeff",
   secondName: "Pasty",
   children: ["Mike"]
  }];

  $scope.allChildren = people.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b.children) },[]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat='child in allChildren'>{{ child }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: small bug ... add another parent with children. reduce throws error since returning an array that doesn't have `children` property

Comment: could do `people.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b.children)
  },[]);`

Comment: @charlietfl Thankyou for pointing that out, very helpful, have edited to include your sugegstion

Comment: That's it! Can't believe it didn't occur to me to store it in a new variable. Great advice - thanks to both.